# iPhone - Why do I get a leak?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I get a leak on the code below, any idea why? I am not allocating anything so why does it leak? It leaks 32 bytes

```
NSString *username = @"";
NSString *myString  = @"some text";
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"username="];
//instrument shows a leak on the line below
username = [myString substringToIndex:range.location + range.length];
//I never release username or myString
```

[image]

Comment: Where does `range` come from, and what is its value?

Comment: I edited the code, and range is shown. the values of range depends on the string which is being read by the socket from my server

Comment: You are running on hardware right?

Comment: the range is not a problem, it is a struct:)

Comment: it does leak, and yes i am running on the device

Comment: If you run the code more than once, does it leak more than once?  If not, file a bug because it is probably a false positive.  If it does, either provide more code or, if that is it, file a bug 'cause that ain't right.

Comment: why do you set username to @"" first ?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't have any leaks, myString and userName is autoreleased already. Maybe it is not released yet but it will be released in some future time

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the String has been autoreleased - so should get released on the next pass through the event loop (#2 shows an autorelease).